# PHP array_diff: strange behaviour

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 identical PHP arrays. There is only one value different. I want to find this value:

```
var_dump(array_diff(array(
  "a" => "1",
  "b" => "SomeString",
  "c" => 1, // <- different value, same key 
  "d" => "4521",
  "e" => "7546654241",
  "f" => "78",
  "g" => "99.999",
  "h" => "34",
  "i" => "http://google.com/"
), array(
  "a" => "1",
  "b" => "SomeString",
  "c" => "0", // <- different value, same key 
  "d" => "4521",
  "e" => "7546654241",
  "f" => "78",
  "g" => "99.999",
  "h" => "34",
  "i" => "http://google.com/"
)));
```

The result is `array(0) { }` but there should be new `"c"` value but isn't. When I remove all others values:

```
var_dump(array_diff(array(
  "c" => 1
), array(
  "c" => "0"
)));
```

I get what I want `array(1) { ["c"]=> int(1) }`.

I don't understad it. Why is it so?

Comment: maybe this will work better for you http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

array_diff() matches ***values*** from the first array to the second

`returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.`

The value `1` for key `c` in the first array ***does*** exist in the second array as the value for key `a`, so there is no difference there that array_diff() will recognise

Perhaps using [array_diff_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) will gve you the result that you're actually trying to get.... http://ideone.com/xHCVfF

Comment: Do you mean `array_diff_assoc()`? Good explanation of why OP is not getting what they expect.

Comment: @Mike - I was just typing array_diff_assoc into  ideone.com :)

Answer (score 2):

i tried with http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php and i get

```
array (size=1)
  'c' => int 1
```

as for using array_diff it compares values...